# C#, How to design multiple interfaces to have access to the same delegates?

Tags: c#, interface, delegates, soa

Grabbing my boss's code, which is a service orientated architecture, I have an interface like the one below:

```
namespace MyCompany.Namespace
{
    delegate void DataEvent(string id, IDataFrame frame);
    delegate void LogMessage(MessageType type, string id, string message);
    delegate void ReadyStateChanged(string id, Device state);

    interface IDeviceService
    {
        void Trigger();
        void Start();
        void Stop();

        event DataEvent NewDataFrame;
        event LogMessage LogMessage;
        event ReadyStateChanged StateChanged;

        void ChangeState(Device newState);

        // other method stubs
    }
}
```

This interface is used to build a Device Service, which uses delegates to pass events back and forth from a separate thread to a main object on another thread. I would like to build another service which uses a similar model. I believe the new service will need to be based on a different interface though, so I will have to create another interface. I'd like the new interface to use the same delegates as above, but since the delegates above are defined outside the interface, in the overall namespace, I can't redefine them (this makes sense).

If I would like two (or more) interfaces in the same namespace to be able to use the same delegates, what should I do? Can I create a "super-interface" which stores the delegates? Or a superclass which has the delegates? Maybe a better design exists?

Comment: The current design should work for reusing those delegates with other events in other interfaces.  But if you have trouble using those delegates in practice, perhaps the only problem is the access modifier (or absence of one).  What if you just marked your delegates `public`?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question, but if all the interfaces are in the same namespace, there shouldn't be a problem.. Could you please let me know if that's what you meant or I'm missing the point?

```
// InterfaceTest1.cs
namespace MyCompany.Namespace
{
    delegate void DataEvent(string id, string frame);
    delegate void LogMessage(int type, string id, string message);
    delegate void ReadyStateChanged(string id, string state);

    interface IDeviceService
    {
        void Trigger();
        void Start();
        void Stop();

        event DataEvent NewDataFrame;
        event LogMessage LogMessage;
        event ReadyStateChanged StateChanged;

        void ChangeState(string newState);

        // other method stubs
    }
}

// InterfaceTest2.cs
namespace MyCompany.Namespace
{
    interface IAnotherInterface
    {
        void Test();

        event DataEvent NewDataFrame;
        event LogMessage LogMessage;
        event ReadyStateChanged StateChanged;
    }
}

// TesterClass1.cs
using MyCompany.Namespace;

namespace SearchInFile
{
    class TesterClass1 : IDeviceService
    {
        public void Trigger()
        {

        }

        public void Start()
        {

        }

        public void Stop()
        {

        }

        public void ChangeState(string newState)
        {

        }

        public event DataEvent NewDataFrame;
        public event LogMessage LogMessage;
        public event ReadyStateChanged StateChanged;

        protected virtual void OnNewDataFrame(string id, string frame)
        {
            NewDataFrame?.Invoke(id, frame);
        }
        protected virtual void OnLogMessage(int type, string id, string message)
        {
            LogMessage?.Invoke(type, id, message);
        }
        protected virtual void OnStateChanged(string id, string state)
        {
            StateChanged?.Invoke(id, state);
        }
    }
}

// TesterClass2.cs
using MyCompany.Namespace;

namespace SearchInFile
{
    class TesterClass2 : IAnotherInterface
    {
        public void Test()
        {

        }

        public event DataEvent NewDataFrame;
        public event LogMessage LogMessage;
        public event ReadyStateChanged StateChanged;

        protected virtual void OnNewDataFrame(string id, string frame)
        {
            NewDataFrame?.Invoke(id, frame);
        }
        protected virtual void OnLogMessage(int type, string id, string message)
        {
            LogMessage?.Invoke(type, id, message);
        }
        protected virtual void OnStateChanged(string id, string state)
        {
            StateChanged?.Invoke(id, state);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that what you have here is correct and would work, and I arrived at a similar solution. Both interfaces CAN of course use the same delegate while both interfaces are in the same namespace, but what if I moved IDeviceService into a different namespace? It seems like having 1 interface which defines all delegates would be helpful, but of course we can't define delegates inside an interface...sorry if I seem confused, I don't fully 'get' delegates just yet, and the patterns for using them.

Comment: if you would like to have a shared interface for shared namespaces, did you considered building a shared-dll? just add an addition library project to your solution, write your interface there and add it as a reference to all other projects - no matter what the namespace is.